# How to enable UTF 8 Support PCRE xampp for Windows?

Tags: php, utf-8, kohana, xampp, pcre

I am trying to get the Kohana PHP Framework to work on my localhost using xampp on windows, the problem is: PCRE UTF-8  PCRE has not been compiled with UTF-8 support.

Can Anyone help me how to do this on windows?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone reported (and solved) this problem on [Kohana forums](http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/3444/solved-pcre-has-not-been-compiled-with-unicode-property-support./p1). He's running Kohana on Linux though. In summary, he installed the latest PCRE with enabled UTF-8 support then recompiled PHP.

You can get a Windows version of PCRE with UTF-8 support [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/files/pcre/7.0/pcre-7.0-bin.zip/download) and build PHP using [this guide](https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild).

(Sorry, I can't post comments yet: what's your XAMPP version, btw? I'm also running Kohana (3.2) on it but didn't encounter this problem.)

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help, the solution was really simple and I feel stupid: I downloaded the install.php in ASCII ... that way it reported me that UTF-8 was not supported because obviously the test had to fail in ASCII. The solution was to convert the install.php to UTF-8